# cluster_edge_betweenness in igraph from named one-mode matrix

Tags: r, igraph, network-analysis

I want to use the igraph function `cluster_edge_betweenness` to cluster a one-mode network matrix for plotting, which works, as far as I understand in this way:

```
library("igraph")

adjm <- matrix(sample(0:1, 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.9,0.1)), nc=10)
colnames(adjm) <- LETTERS[1:10]
row.names(adjm) <- LETTERS[1:10]

g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(adjm,
                                 mode = "undirected",
                                 weighted = "weight",
                                 diag = TRUE,
                                 add.colnames = NULL)
c <- cluster_edge_betweenness(g,
                              weights = igraph::E(g)$weight, 
                              edge.betweenness = TRUE, 
                              merges = TRUE, 
                              bridges = TRUE,
                              modularity = FALSE, 
                              membership = FALSE)
```

However, this gives me the error:

```
Error in names(res) <- communities$names : 
'names' attribute [10] must be the same length as the vector [0]
```

This is rather strange since names should be assigned when `add.colnames = NULL`, at least if I understand the help correctly:

> add.colnames
>   Character scalar, whether to add the column names as
>   vertex attributes. If it is ‘NULL’ (the default) then, if present,
>   column names are added as vertex attribute ‘name’.

And then, what is even stranger, despite the error (not a warning!) `cluster_edge_betweenness` actually produces the object I wanted and I can plot it:

```
hc <- as.hclust(c, hang = -1, use.modularity = FALSE)
plot(hc)
```

[image]

What is going on here? Should I file an issue on their GitHub page or is there something I'm misunderstanding?

Note: Tested with igraph 1.2.1.

Comment: I ran your code and got no error message. What happens for you if you restart R and run nothing but the code in your question?

Comment: @G5W thanks for testing!!! I just tried restarting R and also tried on a different PC with different OS and different R version. Still the same result. Could you maybe check `packageVersion("igraph")` for me? Thanks

Comment: I am using version 1.0.1

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem with 1.1.2

Comment: As just for fixing the problem, it seems to be quite easy: it is `membership = FALSE` what causes it. Setting it to `TRUE` fixes the issue.

Comment: I downgraded to 1.0.1 but still got this error... not sure how that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is thrown in the function `membership`:

```
function (communities) 
{
    if (!is.null(communities$membership)) {
        res <- communities$membership
    }
    else if (!is.null(communities$merges) && !is.null(communities$modularity)) {
        res <- community.to.membership2(communities$merges, communities$vcount, 
            which.max(communities$modularity))
    }
    else {
        stop("Cannot calculate community membership")
    }
    if (igraph_opt("add.vertex.names") && !is.null(communities$names)) {
        names(res) <- communities$names
    }
    class(res) <- "membership"
    res
}
```

The problem seems to be that `communities$membership` is `numeric(0)`. Due to that `res` also becomes `numeric(0)` and, since

```
communities$names
# [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J"
```

we get the error in `names(res) <- communities$names`.

Hence, it looks like a bug coming from somewhere before and, as I commented, a quick fix is setting `membership = TRUE` when calling `cluster_edge_betweenness`.

Comment: Was just about to answer to your comment. Your fix changes the order in `hclust` but works perfectly otherwise (the order is not really important anyway as long as the clusters stay the same).